# SQL - Join, but include null results (as if there was no join)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have a `Contacts` table and a `Businesses` table, they are joined via a `Contacts_vs_Businesses` table (it's a many-to-many relationship).

I want to query the two tables; if a contact is related to two businesses, I want to return:

- A row with all contact details and all details of Business A;
- A row with all contact details and all details of Business B
- A row with all contact details and NO business details at all (as if I'd just done a basic `SELECT` on the first table)

Contacts Table

```
ID Contact_Name Contact_Phone
1  Jez Clark    01234 567 890
2  Someone Else 01254 648 654
```

Businesses Table

```
ID Business_Name   Business_Address
1  A Company       24, A Street, A Town
2  Another Company 43, Another Street, Another Town
```

Contacts_vs_Businesses

```
Contact_ID Business_ID
1          1
1          2
2          2
```

I want to return:

```
Contact_Name Contact_Phone Business_Name   Business_Address
Jez Clark    01234 567 890 A Company       24, A Street, A Town
Jez Clark    01234 567 890 Another Company 43, Another Street, Another Town
Jez Clark    01234 567 890 NULL            NULL
```

I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2.

How would I go about this (I'm guessing it's something REALLY easy...)? I've tried the various permutations of OUTER and INNER and LEFT/RIGHT joins, but none seem to give me that last line of results.

Thanks

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` should give you the desired output. Can we see your query?

Comment: Show us what you already have.  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Why would you want the third row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, for any contact that is associated with 2 businesses, you want to show that contact with each business, followed by a NULL business, resulting in 3 records?

Try something like this using `GROUP BY` to get counts and `UNION` to return the NULL record:

```
SELECT C.Contact_Name, C.Contact_Phone, B.Business_Name, B.BusinessAddress
FROM Contacts C
  INNER JOIN Contacts_vs_Businesses CB ON C.Id = CB.Contact_ID
  INNER JOIN Businesses B ON CB.Business_Id = B.Id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT Contact_ID, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Contacts_vs_Businesses GROUP BY Contact_ID) CB2 ON C.Contact_ID = CB2.Contact_Id      
WHERE CB2.cnt = 2
UNION
SELECT C.Contact_Name, C.Contact_Phone, NULL, NULL
FROM Contacts
   INNER JOIN Contacts_vs_Businesses CB ON C.Contact_ID = CB.Contact_Id      
GROUP BY C.Contact_Name, C.Contact_Phone
HAVING Count(*) = 2
```

Good luck.

Comment: *slaps forehead* That may well be it. Let me check.

Comment: Good stuff -- I updated the answer slightly removing one of the unneeded subqueries -- glad I could help.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial query, since it requires joins and unions.  The first two items are pretty standard.  Bringing in the third is where the `union all` is needed:

```
select Contact_Name, Contact_Phone, Business_Name, Business_Address
from Contacts_vs_Businesses cb join
     Businesses b
     on cb.Business_Id = b.id join
     Contacts c
     on cb.Contact_Id = c.id
union all
select Contact_Name, Contact_Phone, NULL, NULL
from Contacts
where Contact_Id in (select Contact_id
                     from Contacts_vs_Businesses cb
                     group by Contact_id
                     having COUNT(*) = 2
                    )
```